# Will using Arrays.asList() to append to/remove from original array work?

Tags: java, arrays

I ran into a Java EE method with some codes like this:

```
(new ArrayList<Customer>(Arrays.asList(Customers))).add(((Customer) event.getObject()))
```

This is a single line of code from a Managed Bean, which makes use of some Primefaces features (the "event" here is a Primefaces datatable select event, basically it allows user to select entries on data table and to add/remove from an ARRAY of Customer objects, the removing code is quite similar, the only difference is it removes an `Customer` object from the list ). And there is no further code to convert the newly constructed ArrayList back to an array and set the array a new on.

In the code, `Customers` is the array which the code is appending to/removing from, all I can see from this line of code is that it creates an ArrayList from the Array `Customers` and appending another `Customer` object to the list, but from actual usage this line of code seems to be able to increase the size of the array and append the new object to it.

So I guess my question is: is this really a legit way to resize and append to/remove from a fixed size array? Or is it something I have missed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try it out? http://ideone.com/NbXnoz

Comment: @Radiodef thank you! I tried it, it does not seem to alter the original array.

Comment: How is this jsf or PrimeFaces related

Comment: @Kukeltje because on the front end I used Primefaces to display a data table that allows the user to select entries on the table and manipulate managed bean fields (in my case, the size of the array and objects stored in it). I am still not sure what is making the changes. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't change the length of the original array (`Customers`), which is not possible. It creates a new `ArrayList` that is initialized by the elements of the fixed length `List` returned by `Arrays.asList`, and adds an element to that new `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried something and it seems it is something else changing the size of the array. Probably Primefaces selection datatable :/

Comment: @RuiChen the length of the array can't be changed. Perhaps a new array is created somewhere and is assigned to the `Customers` variable.

Comment: That is what I think, I was not sure since that line of code seems to be the only method actively changing the array from the managed bean. Maybe I should open another thread on this since I am quite confused right now. :/